# Default Programe

Tags: firefox-3.6

I wanted to set a default programe for need for speed and i set internet exprore but all file have started to open in internet exprore what should i do to remove internet exprorer as a default programe.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the file and choose *open with* then *Choose Program...*.

Choose the program from the list (or click browse to find it) then at the bottom check *Always use the selected program to open this kind of file*.

Answer (score 1):

You can also, inside Firefox, go to Tools top menu, then Options, click on "Advanced" icon, and in "General" tab, in the last bottom area, set checked that Firefox is the browser by default, you can even hit the button to check now if it is actually the default browser.